# PL SQL not able to read from file

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am new to PL/SQL and am trying to read from a file through PL/SQL as below. I keep getting "ORA-20000" for this. Is there something wrong I am doing?

```
declare

  output_file  utl_file.file_type;
  firstline    VARCHAR2(1000);
  secondline   VARCHAR2(1000);

BEGIN
  output_file := utl_file.fopen (&1,&2, 'W');
  utl_file.fclose(output_file);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN utl_file.invalid_path THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'ERROR: INVALID PATH FOR FILE.');
END;
/
```

Comment: my suggestion is to use sqlldr (or another language like C# or Java) to load the file first.  Once in an Oracle table (a staging table), manipulate as needed.

Answer (score 5):

Presumably, this is a SQL*Plus script, right?  What values are you providing for the two substitution variables?

Are you trying to read a file on the server?  Or on your local client machine?

Have you created an Oracle directory object that matches the name of the directory object you are entering at runtime?

Comment: I have given the path for a the local client machine. I have no idea what an Oracle directory object is. now since you mentioned it I saw in google that I need to create a directory object and map it to my local client machine. Is this correct?

Comment: @Vabs - PL/SQL runs on the database server.  That means that it can only access files that are stored on the database server.  Code running in the database cannot access files stored on your local client machine.

Comment: @Vabs - See APC's answer.  Generally, as he indicates, you want to move the filr to the server first.

Answer (score 5):

> "I have given the path for a the local
>   client machine"

PL/SQL runs on the database server and it can only see directories which are visible from that box.  This is normally just directories which are local *to the server*, unless you also have mapped network drives.  So, unless you are sharing your local PC drive with the database server PL/SQL won't be able to access your files.

Bear in mind that directory permissions apply as well; the database can only read and write to directories if the OS `oracle` user or `dba` group (or Windows equivalents) can read and write them.  [Find out more](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm#i996762).

---

Note that the OS user privileges merely form the pool of potentially accessible directories.  By default the database has no access to any OS directories.

When UTL_FILE was first introduced (Oracle 7 I think) its accessible directory paths were defined by the UTL_FILE_DIR parameter in the `init.ora` file.    This was both inconvenient - we had to restart the database in order to apply a change - and also insecure, because read and write access was granted globally, on all directories to all users.

In Oracle 9i we gained the database DIRECTORY object.  This is neat because we can create or drop a DIRECTORY with straight DDL, so no restarts are required.  Even better, privileges on the DIRECTORY are granted to named users, and we can distinguish READ or WRITE privileges.

But with both cases we have to use absolute file paths.  No relative paths, no wildcards.

The syntax is covered in Oracle's online documentation.  [Find out more](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5007.htm#i2061958).

---

> "so how can I acess files on my local
>   client machine?"

One solution is to share your local drive with the network.  This is rarely desirable.

A more practical solution is to move files from your local drive to the database server, using something like `ftp`.  How you implement that depends on the details of your situation.  If this is an ad hoc requirement then command-line `ftp` or good old WinSCP will suffice.  If this is something you need for regular users then you'll probably want to build a wrapped piece of functionality into your application.